# Keep colums while grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am a beginner in R and was looking for help online, but the examples I found among similar titles don't quite fit my needs, because they only deal with few colums.
I have a data.frame T1 with over 100 columns and what I am looking for is something like a summary, but I want to retain every other column after the summary. I thought about using aggregate but since it's not a function, I am uncertain. The most promising way I think of you can see below.

```
T2 <- T1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(AGI = paste(AGI, collapse = "; "))
```

The summary works the way I want, but I lose any other column.

I definitly appreciate any kind of advice! Thank you very much

Comment: Without example data I can't confirm, but I think you're looking for `mutate` instead of `summarize`.  It doesn't seem like you're actually summarizing anything, just modifying the AGI field.

Comment: @TTS the data looks like this. As you can see, one ID can have several AGIs and the otherway round, so I want to collapse everthing and reduce row number 'ID UniProt_Accession       AGI
1  1            P25702 AT1G54630
2  1            F4HWZ6 AT1G54630
3  2            Q9C5M0 AT5G19760
4  3            Q9SR37 AT3G09260
5  3            Q9LKR7 AT5G28510
6  4            Q9FXI7 AT1G19890'

Comment: What do you want to do with the remaining columns? Either they are grouping variables or they have to be summarized in some way. Could you add the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on TTS's comment, if you want to keep any other column you have to use `mutate` instead of `summarise` because, as the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) says, `summarise()` creates a new data frame.

You should therefore use

```
T1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(AGI = paste(AGI, collapse = "; ")) %>% ungroup()
```

#### Data

```
T1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), UniProt_Accession = c("P25702", 
"F4HWZ6", "Q9C5M0", "Q9SR37", "Q9LKR7", "Q9FXI7"), AGI = c("AT1G54630", 
"AT1G54630", "AT5G19760", "AT3G09260", "AT5G28510", "AT1G19890"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#      ID UniProt_Accession AGI                 
#   <int> <chr>             <chr>               
# 1     1 P25702            AT1G54630; AT1G54630
# 2     1 F4HWZ6            AT1G54630; AT1G54630
# 3     2 Q9C5M0            AT5G19760           
# 4     3 Q9SR37            AT3G09260; AT5G28510
# 5     3 Q9LKR7            AT3G09260; AT5G28510
# 6     4 Q9FXI7            AT1G19890
```